# What is the vim command to jump to linked line inside markdown document?

Tags: filetype-markdown

I have created a table of contents at the beginning of my markdown document and linked the headers of the document:

```
# TOC
[first header](#first-header)

# first header
```

Now, having opened the document in vim, I want to jump from the reference in the table of contents directly to the respective header. What is the keystroke combination? I found out that with `gf` I can jump to linked files, but for my case everything is in the same document.

Comment: There is no such command in vim. You can create it yourself though.

Comment: If you want even easier navigation I have a plugin that shows all sections in a popup and let's you jump to the selected section header. However, I have yet to advertise it (i.e. it's not widely shared) and the Markdown support is new and not heavily tested (I wrote it for Asciidoc originally) so you'd kind of be a beta tester. ;)  Still, if you're interested: https://github.com/b-layer/musecnav (currently Vim only since Neovim has totally different "popups")

Comment: Relatedly, a simple section jumper is `:vimgrep /^#/ %`; I've customized mine a bit more [here](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/autoload/bk/markdown.vim#L44) and [here](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/6853f7102a1ce4599da62b836ad2f33406ac8622/links/vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim#L24)

Comment: Thank you @D.BenKnoble, my workaround is something similar, such a sequential search gets just a bit cumbersome  with a lot of headers.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any built in vim functionality that works like this, but here are 2 options:

- Use the link text to search for the heading. e.g. `vi[y/<c-r>0<cr>`

  - `vi[` visually select inner square brackets
  - `y` copy the selection
  - `/` start a search
  - `<c-r>0` to access register 0 (the most recent yank)
  - `<cr>` Enter
- Use the *vim-markdown* plugin. It allows you to follow named anchors with the `ge` command. See here -> https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown#follow-named-anchors

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The first suggestion only works if there are no other occurrences of that specific word in the document. I cannot get the second suggestion to run. If I understand the syntax correctly, if one wants to search in the same file, one writes instead of `file#anchor` only `#anchor` and sets `let g:vim_markdown_follow_anchor = 1`, navigates to the anchor and hits `ge`. For me, it is just jumping a few characters backwards. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you’re doing it correctly, maybe reach out to the library maintainers on GitHub for help. You could also look through some GitHub issues to see if others have had the same problem

Answer (score 3):

One maybe even more elegant solution than manually generating a table of contents is to use the `:Toc` functionality from the *vim-markdown* plugin (see https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown#commands). This function opens a new window with a navigatable table of contents.